# Vue.js Component with v-model

Tags: input, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

I have been able to accomplish a single level deep of v-model two-way binding on a custom component, but need to take it one level deeper.

Current working code:

```
    <template lang="html">

      <div class="email-edit">

        <input ref="email" :value="value.email" @input="updateInput()"/>
<input ref="body" :value="value.body" @input="updateInput()"/>

      </div>

    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      import LineEditor from './LineEditor.vue'
      export default {
        components: {
          LineEditor
        },
        computed: {
        },
        methods: {
          updateInput: function(){
            this.$emit('input',{
              email: this.$refs.email.value,
              body: this.$refs.body.value
            })
          }
        },
        data: function(){
          return {}
        },
        props: {
          value: {
            default: {
              email: "",
              body: ""
            },
            type:Object
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Used like this: `<email-edit-input v-model="emailModel" />`

However, if I add this piece, the value no longer propagates upwards:

```
      <div class="email-edit">

        <line-editor ref="email" :title="'Email'" :value="value.email" @input="updateInput()"/>
<input ref="body" :value="value.body" @input="updateInput()"/>

      </div>

    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      import LineEditor from './LineEditor.vue'
      export default {
        components: {
          LineEditor
        },
        computed: {
        },
        methods: {
          updateInput: function(){
            this.$emit('input',{
              email: this.$refs.email.value,
              body: this.$refs.body.value
            })
          }
        },
        data: function(){
          return {}
        },
        props: {
          value: {
            default: {
              email: "",
              body: ""
            },
            type:Object
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Using this second custom component:

```
<template lang="html">

  <div class="line-edit">
    <div class="line-edit__title">{{title}}</div>
    <input class="line-edit__input" ref="textInput" type="text" :value="value" @input="updateInput()" />
  </div>

</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  export default {
    components: {
    },
    computed: {
    },
    methods: {
      updateInput: function(){
        this.$emit('input', this.$refs.textInput.value)
      }
    },
    data: function(){
      return {}
    },
    props: {
      title:{
        default:"",
        type:String
      },
      value: {
        default: "",
        type: String
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The first code-block works fine with just an input. However, using two custom components does not seem to bubble up through both components, only the LineEditor. How do I get these values to bubble up through all custom components, regardless of nesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated your code a bit to handle using v-model on your components so that you can pass values down the tree and also back up the tree. I also added watchers to your components so that if you should update the email object value from outside the email editor component, the updates will be reflected in the component.

```js
console.clear()

const LineEditor = {
  template:`
    <div class="line-edit">
      <div class="line-edit__title">{{title}}</div>
      <input class="line-edit__input" type="text" v-model="email" @input="$emit('input',email)" />
    </div>
  `,
  watch:{
    value(newValue){
      this.email = newValue
    }
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      email: this.value
    }
  },
  props: {
    title:{
      default:"",
      type:String
    },
    value: {
      default: "",
      type: String
    }
  }
}

const EmailEditor = {
  components: {
    LineEditor
  },
  template:`
    <div class="email-edit">
      <line-editor :title="'Email'" v-model="email" @input="updateInput"/>
      <input :value="value.body" v-model="body" @input="updateInput"/>
    </div>
  `,
  watch:{
    value(newValue){console.log(newValue)
      this.email = newValue.email
      this.body = newValue.body
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput: function(value){
      this.$emit('input', {
        email: this.email,
        body: this.body
      })
    },
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      email: this.value.email,
      body: this.value.body
    }
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      default: {
        email: "",
        body: ""
      },
      type: Object
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    email: {}
  },
  components:{
    EmailEditor
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <email-editor v-model="email"></email-editor>
  <div>
    {{email}}
  </div>
  <button @click="email={email:'testing@email', body: 'testing body' }">change</button>
</div>
```

In the example above, entering values in the inputs updates the parent. Additionally I added a button that changes the parent's value to simulate the value changing *outside* the component and the changes being reflected in the components.

There is no real reason to use `ref`s at all for this code.

Comment: These seems to be a more complete solution. I've added it into my codebase, and it works. Just to be sure I follow your logic. Props pass down to the child, the child uses a watcher to catch any changes from the parent to the props and adjust its instance scoped variables accordingly. The instance scope variables, data, are used for the inputs as v-model to maintain what the user edits are, and pass up to the parent through the emit on input. Does this cover your logic chain?

Comment: @steventnorris You got it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, having the passthrough manually done on both components did not work. However, replacing my first custom component with this did:

```
<line-editor ref="email" :title="'Email'" v-model="value.email"/>
<input ref="body" :value="value.body" @input="updateInput()"/>
```

Using only v-model in the first component and then allowing the second custom component to emit upwards did the trick.